# Remove terminal first message

Tags: command-line

I have just installed Ubuntu 11.10 and I am getting this message:

```
To run a command as administrator (user "root"), use "sudo <command>".
See "man sudo_root" for details.
```

every time I run a terminal window. How can I disable it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At terminal type `sudo -s` and enter your password.

Comment: This also works in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS